# Convert TimeSpan to String in MVC 3 Controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, linq, sql-server-2008

I have a question , I have a Timespan in my Database and i want to use it in my controller but  this error appears

Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'System.TimeSpan'

Controller :

```
    int id = Convert.ToInt32(clientId);
                        clientShift = (from a in db.Client_Shift
                                        where a.ID == id
                                        select a).SingleOrDefault();

                                    clientShift.DayFrom_LookID = Convert.ToInt32(dateFrom);
                                    clientShift.DayTo_LookID = Convert.ToInt32(dateTo);
This is where the error occur  -->  clientShift.EndTime = endTime.Trim();
                                    clientShift.DateModified = DateTime.UtcNow;
                                    clientShift.ModifiedBy = User.Identity.Name;
```

Model :

```
 public partial class Client_Shift
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public int Client_ID { get; set; }
        public int DayFrom_LookID { get; set; }
        public int DayTo_LookID { get; set; }
        public System.TimeSpan StartTime { get; set; }
        public System.TimeSpan EndTime { get; set; }
```

Thanks for someone who can help me :D

Comment: Use `TimeSpan.Parse(endTime.Trim())` ?

Comment: Hahaha @McGarnagle Thanks again!! We crossed road again huh :))

Answer (score 1):

You need to [`Parse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/se73z7b9.aspx) the `TimeSpan`:

```
clientShift.EndTime = TimeSpan.Parse(endTime.Trim());
```

If the string does not represent a valid time span, you will get an exception.